# DOM manipulation in PHP

Tags: php, html, dom

I am looking for good methods of manipulating HTML in PHP. For example, the problem I currently have is dealing with malformed HTML.

I am getting input that looks something like this:

```
<div>This is some <b>text
```

As you noticed, the HTML is missing closing tags. I could use regex or an XML Parser to solve this problem. However, it is likely that I will have to do other DOM manipulation in the future. I wonder if there are any good PHP libraries that handle DOM manipulation similar to how Javascript deals with DOM manipulation.

Comment: I would run malformed HTML through HTML Purifier before doing anything else with it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

PHP has [a PECL extension that gives you access to the features of HTML Tidy](http://php.net/tidy).  Tidy is a pretty powerful library that should be able to take code like that and close tags in an intelligent manner.

I use it to clean up malformed XML and HTML sent to me by a classified ad system prior to import.

Answer (score 6):

I've found PHP Simple HTML DOM to be the most useful and straight forward library yet. Better than PECL I would say.

I've written an article on [how to use it to scrape myspace artist tour dates](http://www.crainbandy.com/programming/using-php-and-simple-html-dom-parser-to-scrape-artist-tour-dates-off-myspace) (just an example.)  Here's a link to the [php simple html dom parser.](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 3):

The DOM library which is now built-in can solve this problem easily. The loadHTML method will accept malformed XML while the load method will not.

```
$d = new DOMDocument;
$d->loadHTML('<div>This is some <b>text');
$d->saveHTML();
```

The output will be:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html>
  <body>
    <div>This is some <b>text</b></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I entered a similar answer with a bit more on string encoding and how to extract a document fragment [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8500390/fixing-unclosed-html-tags/43212965#43212965)

Answer (score 1):

For manipulating the DOM i think that what you're looking for is [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.dom.php). I've used to parse HTML documents from the web and it worked fine for me.