# Fixing unclosed HTML tags

Tags: php, html, dom

I am working on some blog layout and I need to create an abstract of each post (say 15 of the lastest) to show on the homepage. Now the content I use is already formatted in html tags by the textile library. Now if I use substr to get 1st 500 chars of the post, the main problem that I face is how to close the unclosed tags.

e.g

```
<div>.......................</div>
<div>...........
     <p>............</p>
     <p>...........| 500 chars
     </p>
<div>
```

What I get is two unclosed tags <p> and <div> , p wont create much trouble , but div just messes with the whole page layout. So any suggestion how to track the opening tags and close them manually or something?

Comment: Push opening tags onto a stack, and pop off ones which are closed. Take into account self closing tags. When you have consumed enough text characters, serialise the remaining tags into closing tags, last on first out.

Comment: There is a similar discussion related to DOM manipulation using PHP [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27222/583539).

Comment: yea @alex i thought of that, trying to implement itm is there any example i can follow ?

Comment: `<p>` tags don't need to be closed unless in XHTML. Do we assume you're using XHTML?

Comment: no i am using html. and as i said `<p>` is fine .. they are auto closed , but its the div tags causing the main layout problems

Answer (score 18):

There are lots of methods that can be used:

1. Use a proper HTML parser, like [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php)
2. Use [PHP Tidy](http://www.php.net/manual/en/tidy.repairstring.php) to repair the un-closed tag
3. Some would suggest [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/)

Comment: nice, php tidy were really simple.

Comment: tidy is great for easy, quick and dirty. Err, I mean cleaning. HTML Purifier is a BEAST and great for complex rulesets.

Answer (score 18):

As ajreal said, DOMDocument is a solution.

Example :

```
$str = "
<html>
 <head>
  <title>test</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <p>error</i>
 </body>
</html>
";

$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($str);
echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

Advantage : natively included in PHP, contrary to PHP Tidy.

Comment: I appreciate this is a simple answer if you are dealing with a simple problem, and don't want the overhead of installing any extra libraries.  In my case, I had users pasting incomplete HTML from emails and Word, and this fixed it.

Comment: That was exactly the kind of clean answer I was looking for. Thanks so much for that.

Comment: I had to use `@$doc->loadHTML(utf8_decode($html))` but thank you for this useful answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use DOMDocument to do it, but be careful of string encoding issues. Also, you'll have to use a complete HTML document, then extract the components you want. Here's an example:

```
function make_excerpt ($rawHtml, $length = 500) {
  // append an ellipsis and "More" link
  $content = substr($rawHtml, 0, $length)
    . '&hellip; <a href="/link-to-somewhere">More &gt;</a>';

  // Detect the string encoding
  $encoding = mb_detect_encoding($content);

  // pass it to the DOMDocument constructor
  $doc = new DOMDocument('', $encoding);

  // Must include the content-type/charset meta tag with $encoding
  // Bad HTML will trigger warnings, suppress those
  @$doc->loadHTML('<html><head>'
    . '<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset='
    . $encoding . '"></head><body>' . trim($content) . '</body></html>');

  // extract the components we want
  $nodes = $doc->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0)->childNodes;
  $html = '';
  $len = $nodes->length;
  for ($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++) {
    $html .= $doc->saveHTML($nodes->item($i));
  }
  return $html;
}

$html = "<p>.......................</p>
  <p>...........
    <p>............</p>
    <p>...........| 500 chars";

// output fixed html
echo make_excerpt($html, 500);
```

Outputs:

```
<p>.......................</p>
  <p>...........
    </p>
<p>............</p>
    <p>...........| 500 chars… <a href="/link-to-somewhere">More &gt;</a></p>
```

If you are using WordPress you should wrap the `substr()` invocation in a call to `wpautop` - `wpautop(substr(...))`. You may also wish to test the length of the $rawHtml passed to the function, and skip appending the "More" link if it isn't long enough.