# HTML let html elements only affect inside div

Tags: html

i don't know how to solve a special problem.
I searched for it in google but i can't anything, probably because i don't have a correct keywords to find a solution.

I will explain my problem with an example:

```
<div>
    <label>Message</label>
    <div id="messageContent">
        <b>Title:</b>
        The content of the message
        <u>Other type of content
    </div>
    <div id="differentContent">
        The content of this div should not be affected by the "<u>" of the messageContent div
    </div>
</div>
```

My problem now is that I have a div where I display different messages and if there is anything without a closing tag it does also affect every following text on the page and sometimes it also destroy the structure of the page.
What I want is that everything inside the `messageContent` div does not affect anything outside of it.

Comment: The content of the #messageContent is dynamic right? Have you tried using Js? `document.createTextNode('<p>Stuff</p>');`

Answer (score 3):

In HTML, every tag that is once opened needs to be closed. Since you have an opened `u` tag that is never closed, your browser applies the appropriate styling (in this case an underline) to the end of the page. To fix this problem, you simply need to close the tag where you want it to end, like this :

```
<u>Other type of content</u>
```

In the `differentContent` `div`, since you're trying to display the tag as plain text, you'll need to escape these string by using the appropriate character: `&lt;u&gt;`

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Fixing unclosed HTML tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8500390/fixing-unclosed-html-tags)
It provides both server-side (PHP Tidy)or JS-side solutions. 
I would add that you can also try using jQuery's parser if you use jQuery, its parser guarantees the DOM is well formatted, but it may fail when the input is too malformed:

```
$('#messageContent').html('<div>a<div>b');
```