# Filter names and surnames with regex

Tags: php, regex

in my PHP script I have a variable like the following:

```
$names = '<a href="%URL$%" rel="tag">Name Surname</a>, <a href="%URL$%" rel="tag">Name Surname</a>, <a href="%URL$%" rel="tag">Name Surname</a>';
```

Is it possible to filter $names in order to have this result?

```
$names = '<a href="%URL$%" rel="tag">N. Surname</a>, <a href="%URL$%" rel="tag">N. Surname</a>, <a href="%URL$%" rel="tag">N. Surname</a>';
```

Comment: Yes, using [DOM manipulation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27222/dom-manipulation-in-php). A regex is [not going to help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

Comment: What do you mean by filter? You just want to replace "Name" with "N.". Are there other requirements?

Comment: Yes, I obviously have different names and I'd like to take only the first character followed by a dot. ex: John Smith, Mark Twain => J. Smith, M. Twain

Answer (score 0):

You could use `preg_replace_callback`:

```
$names = preg_replace_callback(
             '/(<a[^>]*>)(\w+)( \w+</a>)',
             function($matches) {
                 return $matches[1] . substr($matches[2], 0, 1) . "." . $matches[3];
             },
             $names
         );
```

Answer (score -1):

Really short answer: Use a HTML parser (like http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

Regexes and HTML only work when you are sure you are only pulling apart a really predictable string of code.